# Product data is not export in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.8.1 and I want to change some data. for this I have created data-flow profile. It is working fine in localhost but it is not working on the server. After click on run in popup, on localhost the file is transfer but it not happened same on the server.

See here to enter the detail while creating data-flow profile.

[image: dataflow profile]

Answer (score 0):

Using Magento Data-Flow is a pain. Learn Magmi, it will be helpful in the long run as well.